# Oracle Jet table data not refreshing when oj-option button is toggled

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

I have a data table using oracle jet with 3 oj-option buttons to toggle between 3 different sets of data that should be fetched when a new option is selected, however its not doing that. How can i get the table or the page to refresh when an oj-option is clicked/toggled?

i created a refresh function thats called for each option when toggled:

```
const refreshData = () => {
           const table = document.getElementById('data-table-exceptions')
            const data = table.demandSensingData
            data.refresh()

            }
```